# Order confirmation devices

Tags: device, point-of-sale

We are building a solution where we have to send orders to our clients whenever a customer places one on our site. To simplify the process we are looking at some kind of low cost order confirmation device where the order can be printed at the clients ends and the client sends a confirmation back.

I have searched for such kind of devices but i only get patent results for such devices.

Comment: I think this belongs on superuser or should be closed

Answer (score 0):

Could your website be changed to email the client when a customer places an order?